# curl won't shut up (--silent does nothing)

Tags: bash, curl

I'm writing a quick shell script, and I cannot for the life of me get `curl` to suppress the progress bar.

The relevant line looks like this:

`curl http://website -o $temp >/dev/null 2>&1`

When I run my script, I still get the progress output.

I've tried adding `-s`, `-sS`, `-s`, `--silent`, and redirecting the output to `/dev/null` as seen above.

How do I get curl to do what it's being told?

Comment: Sounds really strange... what curl / OS version? Works as expected with `curl 7.36.0 (i686-pc-cygwin)`.

Comment: I find that `curl http://website -o temp 2>/dev/null` produces no output on the terminal with curl 7.27.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu). What's in your **temp** variable (maybe something that is affecting the expanded command)?